Use a single seach box to search and show results from different column in query
I started with a full database, query is setup pulling the columns that I want the results to search and pull from, I let the system create the "key" by generating row IDs.
In the form, I have named the search box, and entered a code below query criteria. The first column has Like "*" & [Forms]![CribMasterF]![SearchBox] & "*". The other columns have the same code, linked to the search box in the "or" sections. The problem is, it only searches for matches in the first column of the query, if the results are in the other columns in the query, it just fails and returns an empty result.
Like "*" & [Forms]![CribMasterF]![SearchBox] & "*"
It only scans and pulls results from the first column in the query, if the result is in another column, it just brings back nothing

Are fields all text type? Are any lookup fields? Provide sample data as formatted text table as well as SQL. The approach you describe works for me.

The solution is quite straight-foward. Simply concatenate all the columns you want to include in the search as shown below. The only drawback is that you may find the search criteria gets an inadvertent hit across two fields. For example if fld1='12A' and fld2='A34' and you search for 'AA' then that record will be returned even though 'AA' does not exist in any one field. To avoid this scenario you can include a field delimiter of your choice between each field, preferably one or two characters that are very unlikely to appear in the data. Be creative ;-)
SELECT fldOrder, fldDate
FROM Table1
WHERE [fld1] & [fld2] & [fld3] & [fld4] Like "*" & [Forms]![CribMasterF]![SearchBox] & "*";

Or with a delimiter:
SELECT fldOrder, fldDate
FROM Table1
WHERE [fld1] & "[|" & [fld2] & "[|" & [fld3] & "[|" & [fld4] Like "*" & [Forms]![CribMasterF]![SearchBox] & "*";


As long as fields are not lookups with alias - which could actually be why OP's original query is not working.
